# Getting weird view of Sql database in terminal

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am storing an Image in my sql database of type mediumblob, but when i saw the database after storing it,it show weird look[image: view of image]

i took image in inputstream and convert it in byte[] array and store it in mysql.Why i am getting this?

Database view:-
[image]

Comment: Were you expecting to see Base64? An image, rendered in the terminal as normal? An image converted into ASCII art?

Comment: So is this correct but then how can i see my table if get this type of view, is there any other method to store an image.

Comment: Again, what exactly are you looking for in a plain-text, no-GUI terminal view?

Comment: i want to see my image column in mysql database in text instead of byte[] format.

Comment: And how would the image column look as text?  Usually, for BLOBS, you store them in the file system, because they are so cumbersome to work with in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Blob data types in mysql store the information in encoded form.Hence you can only see the result in garbage form which is not actually garbage but your image in encoded form.Try using mysql workbench GUI interface to see your database in a nice way.